# Why I cannot access k3s service from pod in rasbian?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, networking

I have installed K3S kubernetes on rasbian, and created a following mysql deployment on it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-path
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-config
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-path
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-log
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-path
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    name: mysql
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
      # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
      # Optional field
      # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
      nodePort: 30036
 
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 999 
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: hypriot/rpi-mysql:latest
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: mypassword
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          name: mysql-data
        - mountPath: /var/log/mysql
          name: mysql-log
        - mountPath: /etc/mysql
          name: mysql-config
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-data
      - name: mysql-config
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-config
      - name: mysql-log
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-log
      nodeSelector:
        mysql: master
```

I cannot access mysql by the above definied service:

I have checked the mysql service is accessable:

```
sudo kubectl exec -it mysql-d6656577c-6rdzr bash
root@mysql-d6656577c-6rdzr:/# echo > /dev/tcp/localhost/3306
root@mysql-d6656577c-6rdzr:/# echo $?
0
root@mysql-d6656577c-6rdzr:/# echo > /dev/tcp/mysql-d6656577c-6rdzr/3306
root@mysql-d6656577c-6rdzr:/# echo $?
```

0

But the service is not working:

```
root@mysql-d6656577c-6rdzr:/# echo > /dev/tcp/mysql/3306
bash: mysql: Name or service not known
bash: /dev/tcp/mysql/3306: Invalid argument
root@mysql-d6656577c-6rdzr:/#
```

Service description:

```
sudo kubectl describe svc mysql
Name:              mysql
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=mysql
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"mysql"},"name":"mysql","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"p...
Selector:          app=mysql
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.43.58.35
Port:              mysql  3306/TCP
TargetPort:        3306/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.0.161:3306
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Core DNS logs:

```
sudo kubectl logs -f coredns-d798c9dd-npbj4 --namespace=kube-system
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 4665410bf21c8b272fcfd562c482cb82
   ______                ____  _   _______
  / ____/___  ________  / __ \/ | / / ___/  ~ CoreDNS-1.6.3
 / /   / __ \/ ___/ _ \/ / / /  |/ /\__ \   ~ linux/arm, go1.12.9, 37b9550
/ /___/ /_/ / /  /  __/ /_/ / /|  /___/ / 
\____/\____/_/   \___/_____/_/ |_//____/  
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1587632103.896807637. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.160:34250->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1587632103.896807637. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.160:47752->8.8.4.4:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1587632103.896807637. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.160:57505->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1587632103.896807637. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.160:51583->8.8.4.4:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1587632103.896807637. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.160:39172->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1587632103.896807637. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.160:39568->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1587632103.896807637. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.160:39343->8.8.4.4:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1587632103.896807637. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.160:40929->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1587632103.896807637. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.160:43962->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1587632103.896807637. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.160:47330->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
```

I cannot understand this, because 8.8.8.8 is accessable from host raspberry pi and 8.8.8.8 not contains local dns names (for instance: mysql)

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=10.10 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=11.3 ms
```

What can be the problem? Why I cannot access mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are configuring two services, mysql and mysql-nodeport to use the same port. Without information to indicate otherwise im assuming this is a 1 node setup with rasbian. I personally dont have raspbian installed to test, but try something like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    name: mysql
    targetPort: 3306
    nodePort: 30036
```

Per the kubernetes [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) documentation:
*NodePort: Exposes the Service on each Node's IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You'll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting :*

If you want your service available on the node port, try updating your service and deleting the other service definition.